# Spring RestTemplate ignores XML annoations (eg @XmlAttribute)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, jackson

I'm using `spring-web` to send `POST` xml requests to a webservice. But my Xml bean request does not render the way I defined it with `jaxb` properties:

```
//this class is autogenerated with xsdtojava from *.xsd files
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "myRequest")
public class ServletRequest {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "age")
    private int age;
}
```

Usage:

```
ServletRequest req = new ServletRequest();
req.setAge(20);

restTemplateBuilder.build().postForEntity(url, new HttpEntity<>(req), MyRsp.class);
```

Resulting xml that is send:

```
<ServletRequest>
    <age>20</age>
</ServletRequest>
```

The problem: both the `@XmlRootElement` name and the `@XmlAttribute` annotation seem to be ignored. Why?

Comment: I had similar problems long time ago and i think it is more about Jackson setup then Spring.  You probably already done this,  you have to register Jackson Jaxb module to use jaxb annotations https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations.  I actually ended up using `@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)` and `@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "document")` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation`

Comment: But how can I tell `xsdtojava` to make use of `@JacksonXmlProperty`? I'd rather not want to modify autogenerated classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
            builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
        }
    };
}
```

Or even shorter with java8:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jackson() {
    return (builder) -> builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
}
```

As of jackson `2.9.0` this is part of the core jackson library.

Before, you'd have to add:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.x</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This answer seems to only apply if using Spring Boot.  The Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer class mentioned is in the java package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson